# refresh storyboard view controller after giving height in custom view in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard with a few ViewControllers, in some there is a StackView with the distribution set to 'fill proportionally'.
In the stack view there are views, that are set to be custom views.
I set the views height in code, and play with them a little according to some button clicks.
Everything works just as planned when i run the app, but in the storyboard nothing changes. 
Granted, the changes that i want to make are happing, the only problem is convenience when i want to design in storyboard. 
Is there a way to refresh the storyboard so i can visually see the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Interface Builder can reflect manipulations on the UI in your ViewController or your View by using the keywords IBDesignable/IBInspectable. Check out [this article](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) how to use this feature in xcode.